# Could not autowire. No beans of 'CustomerMapper' type found. can i solved this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**My Customer mapper classs**

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomerMapper {


    ResponseCustomerFilterDTO entityToResponseDTO(Customer customer);
}
```

my customer mapper class.

**Customer Service class**

```
package com.class3.poinofsaleclass3.service;

import java.util.List;

public interface CustomerService {

    String addCustomer(CustomerSaveRequestDTO customerSaveRequestDTO);
    String updateCustomer(CustomerUpdateRequestDTO customerUpdateRequestDTO);
    CustomerDto getCustomerById(int id);
    List<CustomerDto> getAllCustomers();
    CustomerDto getCustomerByNic(String nic);
    ResponseCustomerFilterDTO getCustomerByIdFilter(int id);
}
```

my Customer Service class code

**ResponseCustomerDilterDTO class**

```
package com.class3.poinofsaleclass3.dto.responce;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ResponseCustomerFilterDTO {
    private int customerId;
    private String customerAddress;
    private double customerSalary;
}
```

my ResponseCustomerDilterDTO class  include there

**CustomerServiceIMPL class**

```
package com.class3.poinofsaleclass3.service.impl;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceIMPL implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerMapper customerMapper;  

    @Override
    public String addCustomer(CustomerSaveRequestDTO customerSaveRequestDTO) {

        Customer customer = new Customer(
                customerSaveRequestDTO.getCustomerName(),
                customerSaveRequestDTO.getCustomerAddress(),
                customerSaveRequestDTO.getCustomerSalary(),
                customerSaveRequestDTO.getContactNumber(),
                customerSaveRequestDTO.getNic(),
                false

        );
        if (!customerRepo.existsById(customer.getCustomerId())) {
            customerRepo.save(customer);
            return customer.getCustomerName() + "saved";
        } else {
            System.out.println("customer id already exsit");
            return "customer id already exsit";
        }}

    @Override
    public String updateCustomer(CustomerUpdateRequestDTO customerUpdateRequestDTO) {
        if (customerRepo.existsById(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getCustomerId())) {
            Customer customer = customerRepo.getById(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getCustomerId());
            customer.setCustomerName(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getCustomerName());
            customer.setCustomerAddress(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getCustomerAddress());
            customer.setCustomerSalary(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getCustomerSalary());
            customer.setContactNumber(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getContactNumber());
            customer.setNic(customerUpdateRequestDTO.getNic());
            customer.setActivestate(customerUpdateRequestDTO.isActivestate());
            // System.out.println("customer come"+customer);
            return customerRepo.save(customer).getCustomerName() + "Updated";
        } else {
            System.out.println("this customer not at database");
            return "this customer not at database";
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CustomerDto getCustomerById(int id) {
        Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepo.findById(id);
        if (customer.isPresent()) {
            CustomerDto customerDto =  modelMapper.map(customer.get(),CustomerDto.class);
            return  customerDto;
        }else{
            return  null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<CustomerDto> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> getCustomers = customerRepo.findAll();
        List<CustomerDto> customerDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CustomerDto> customerDtos = modelMapper.map(getCustomers,new TypeToken<List<CustomerDto>>(){}.getType());
 
        return customerDtos;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerDto getCustomerByNic(String nic) {
        Optional <Customer> customer = customerRepo.findByNicEquals(nic);
        if (customer.isPresent()){
            CustomerDto customerDto = modelMapper.map(customer.get(),CustomerDto.class);
            return customerDto;
        }else {
            throw new NotFoundException("not found");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseCustomerFilterDTO getCustomerByIdFilter(int id) {
        Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepo.findById(id);
        if (customer.isPresent()) {
            ResponseCustomerFilterDTO responseCustomerFilterDTO =  customerMapper.entityToResponseDTO(customer.get());
            return responseCustomerFilterDTO;
        }else{
            throw  new  NotFoundException("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

can I use autowired CustomerMapper to my CustomerServiceIMPL? It's showing Could not autowired. No beans of 'CustomerMapper' type found.

Comment: *CustomerMapper* is not a bean, so you can not autowire it. Beans are classes which are annotated with `@Service`, `@Controller`...)

Comment: @Jens but same problem showing to me with using `@Service`,  `@Controller`

Comment: Is the componentScan configured for the package?

Comment: `@Configuration
public class CustomerMappeerConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomerMapper customerMapper(){
        return customerMapper();
    }
}`

Comment: @Jens I did like that any solution?

Comment: That should work if the class with the `@Configuration` annotation is in the component scan path

Comment: Use this two **Dependency** and input below code line to **properties** line
   
             `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
       <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
       <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
      </dependency>  
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
       <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
       <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>`

Comment: **properties** line  
   
     `<properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
     </properties>`